# How to extract outliers from box plot in R

Tags: r, plot

Could you explain me if there is a way to extract outliers from box plot. I have plotted a box plot and I want to extract only the outliers.

Here is the code for the box plot.

```
# melting down
require(reshape)
melt_nx <- melt(nx, id.vars = c("x", "y"))
boxplot(data = melt_nx, main = "NX", value ~ variable, las = 2,    
par(mar = c(15, 5, 4, 2) + 0.1),
names = c("We1", "We2", "we3"))
```

Is it possible from the box plot to extract the outliers only?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example `melt_nx <- melt(nx, id.vars = c("x", "y"))#
Error in is.data.table(data) : object 'nx' not found`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The boxplot function returns a list with one of it node-names as "out". These are the values that are beyond the "whiskers". I don't know about executing `par` within the argument list but if you want these particular values, then use this:

```
vals <- boxplot(data = melt_nx, main = "NX", value ~ variable, las = 2,    
      names = c("We1", "We2", "we3"))
vals$out
```

And do read all these help pages:

```
?boxplot
?boxplot.stats
?bxp
?fivenum
```

Comment: Hi. I test the command it is working. The problem that I face is that in my DF I have one special column serial number is it possible when I extract the outliers to map them according their numbers?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate your assistance. :) It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but for me there is an alternative method using the **Boxplot** method from the **car** package. Note the capital B in the Boxplot function call.

This is the code that does it for me, it returns the row numbers of the outliers which you can then use in your dataframe to filter out or extract, etc...

```
outliers<-Boxplot(x~y, data=df, id.method="y")
```

Note that the extracted values are of type **Character**. Then to exclude them you could do something like:

```
df2 <- df[-as.numeric(outliers),]
```

Hope this helps a little